# Jpa Criteria API, Dynamic Predicates with @OneTomany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Here are my Entities.

#### TradeItem.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRADEITEMS")
public class TradeItem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "TRADEITEM_ID")
private Long id;

private String shopOwner;

private Boolean corrupted;

private String base;

private String type;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Mod> mod;

private String league;

...
}
```

#### Mod.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MODS")
public class Mod {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private Double miniValue;

private Double maxiValue;

private String modName;

...

}
```

#### DaoImpl

```
    @Repository
    public class TradeItemDaoImp implements TradeItemDao{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Optional<List<TradeItem>> search(TradeItemRequest request) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<TradeItem> cq = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(TradeItem.class);

        Root<TradeItem> root = cq.from(TradeItem.class);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new LinkedList<>();


        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("league"), request.getLeague()));

        if(request.getName() != null){
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), "%"+request.getName()+"%"));
        }


        if(request.getType() != null){
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("type"), request.getType()));
        }

        if(request.getBase() != null) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("base"), request.getBase()));
        }


        if(request.getIdentified() != null){
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("identified"), request.getIdentified()));
        }

        if(request.getCorrupted() != null){
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("corrupted"), request.getCorrupted()));
        }

        if(request.getMods().size() > 0) {
            Join<TradeItem, Mod> mod = root.joinSet("mod");

            for (ModRequest m : request.getMods()) {

                predicates.add(
                        criteriaBuilder.and(
                            criteriaBuilder.equal(mod.get("modName"), m.getName()),
                            criteriaBuilder.ge(mod.get("miniValue"), m.getMinValue() == null ? 0 : m.getMinValue()),
                            criteriaBuilder.le(mod.get("maxiValue"), m.getMaxValue() == null ? 10000 : m.getMaxValue()))
                );

            }

        }

        cq.select(root)
                .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

        TypedQuery<TradeItem> typedQuery = em.createQuery(cq);

        return Optional.of(
                typedQuery
                .setFirstResult(0)
                .setMaxResults(50)
                .getResultList());

    }
}
```

Basicly what i am trying to do here is that i have developed a Webscraper for a specific Tradingforum. I have a webapplication where you can search for forum-items through a form. Now each TradingItem contains a set of mods(@OneToMany)  which have different names and values.

When i search for an item with only one or zero mods, it works fine. But as soon as i add two or more mods in the search-form, it returns an empty list.

I'm new to the Criteria Api and there is obviously something wrong with my mod-predicates/logic.

I'm using hibernate 5.1.0 & MySql

[Example of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La83s.png)

### *Edit: Solved*

I simply had to move the Join to inside the for-loop.

```
        for (ModRequest m : request.getMods()) {

            Join<TradeItem, Mod> mod = root.joinSet("mod");
            predicates.add(
                    criteriaBuilder.and(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(mod.get("modName"), m.getName()),
                        criteriaBuilder.ge(mod.get("miniValue"), m.getMinValue() == null ? 0 : m.getMinValue()),
                        criteriaBuilder.le(mod.get("maxiValue"), m.getMaxValue() == null ? 10000 : m.getMaxValue()))
            );

        }
```

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and the generated SQL will probably give you a hint as to what is wrong.

Comment: Don't add the answer in the question body. Instead, create an answer to your own question